# Show all TODO's of the source code after every commit

Tags: git, bash

I want to show every TODO of my source code after each commit. How can I do that using .git/hooks ?

Comment: Please include what you've tried so far and ask a specific question about where and why you got stuck. (If you haven't tried, please do so now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [post-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_commit):

```
 grep -Fr TODO .
```